# Möbius transformation mapping problem

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

> Let $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{R}$ be such that $ad-bc>0$. Consider the Möbius transformation $$T_{a,b,c,d}(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$$
>   and define $$\begin{align}H_{+}&=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\Im(z)>0\},\\H_{-}&=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\Im(z)<0\},\\R_{+}&=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\Re(z)>0\},\\R_{-}&=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\Re(z)<0\}. \end{align}$$
>
> Then $T_{a,b,c,d}$ maps
>
> $$\begin{align}(a)&\quad H_{+} \text{ to } H_{+} \\ (b)&\quad  H_{+} \text{ to } H_{-} \\ (c)&\quad  R_{+} \text{ to } R_{+} \\ (d)&\quad  R_{+} \text{ to } R_{-}\end{align}$$

Usually we know that $$z\in H_{+} \rightarrow \frac{1}{z}\in H_{-}$$ but I didn't get any further... How do we go about solving this problem?

Comment: @ Travis..every thing is correct

Comment: @Psuresh If it is really correct then this is one of the weirdest questions ever, as it is written there "Then $\;.T_{a,b,c,d}\;$ maps" ... Do you really think this is correct, whether it is written that way or not??

Comment: @joanpemo..now i edited the question

Comment: @Psuresh, note that the map $z \to 1/z $ is not a Moebius transformation. However, you can take the map $z \to 1-1/z$ to see that options (c) and (d) are not necessarily correct.

Answer (score 1):

We notice that $T_{a,b,c,d}$ maps $\Bbb R\cup\{\infty\}$ to itself. Hence (a) and (b) are possible options. As $T_{a,b,c,d}(i)=\frac{ai+b}{ci+d}=\frac{(ai+b)(-ci+d)}{(ci+d)(-ci+d)}=\frac{(bd+ac)+(\color{red}{ad-bc})i}{c^2+d^2}$ has positive imaginary part, we see that (a) is certainly valid and (b) false. 
On the other hand, (c) and (d) may or may not be valid.

Comment: The group $Sl(2,\mathbb{R})$ takes $\mathbb{H^{+}}$ to itself. You have made a calculation mistake in the second line.

Comment: answer is from H+ to H+

Comment: @SoumyaSinha Oops, I usually write $x+iy$, not $iy+x$, so I got the conjugate wrong